# helm-projectile: how to search in multiple git repo

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

I use `helm-projectile`in Emacs to search code in my codebase.

The structure of my codebase looks like this:

```
/rootdir
    /project1
        /.git
        /code
        /doc
    /project2
        /.git
        /code
        /doc
    /project3
        /...
```

I have three git repo and I only want to search in their `code` sub-directory. More importantly, when I do `hlem-projectile-ack` in `project1`. I want the search results to include the result from `project2/code` and `project3/code`.

By the default, `helm-projectile` only searches in the current git repo. How can I change the default search root to be `/rootdir` and also effectively ignore everything under `/doc` folders?

Comment: is that really a question about git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by adding a `.projectile` under `/rootdir`

```
+project1/code
+project2/code
+project3
```

Reference: [Projects in Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/master/doc/projects.md).
By the way, the documentation says that contents of `.projectile` are ignored when the
`alien` indexing method is used. I am using `alien` method and adding a `.projecctile` works for me.